# local variable 'features' referenced before assignment in django

Tags: django

hi there i hava simple view where i am trying to pass the features to the html page but its giving me the below error:

```
UnboundLocalError at /enquiry/thanks/
local variable 'features' referenced before assignment
```

And my view

```
 def abc(request):

    features = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
        return render_to_response("xyz/thanks.html",
        {
             'test': features,
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Is that the only code in view? Is indentation correct?

Comment: i haven't placed the rest of the code but the indentation is correct....

Comment: It should have thrown `IndentationError`.Why are you indenting in that way though you didn't get any syntax errors? Try to follow PEP to stay away from weird troubles. Keep the `return` with same indent level of `features`.

Comment: hi there it was actually caused because of the indentation created by the editor, so when i re indented again it worked properly thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
 def abc(request):
    features = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
    return render_to_response("xyz/thanks.html",{
                   'test': features,
           }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```